# Bugs when running the example of go-libp2p-http

Tags: go, libp2p, go-libp2p

The problem lies in **go func**. The error message is **expression in go must be function call**

```
 listener, _ := gostream.Listen(host1, p2phttp.DefaultP2PProtocol)
    defer listener.Close()
    go func() {
        http.HandleFunc("/hello", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            w.Write([]byte("Hi!"))
        })
        server := &http.Server{}
        server.Serve(listener)
    }
```

The error is

**command-line-arguments

.\sever.go:18:5: expression in go must be function call**

Comment: can you post the error too?

Comment: The error is

command-line-arguments
.\sever.go:18:5: expression in go must be function call.
It is for line go func(){....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you decide to make an anonymous function, then**

```
listener, _ := gostream.Listen(host1, p2phttp.DefaultP2PProtocol)
defer listener.Close()
go func() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hi!"))
    })
    server := &http.Server{}
    server.Serve(listener)
}()
```

**Named function:**

```
listener, _ := gostream.Listen(host1, p2phttp.DefaultP2PProtocol)
defer listener.Close()
go Greet()

func Greet() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hi!"))
    })
    server := &http.Server{}
    server.Serve(listener)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to invoke (call) the anonymous function. Hence, the error: *expression in go must be function call*.

```golang
go func() { fmt.Prinln("Im an IIFE") }()  // note the parenthesis
```

This is called immediate invoked function expression (IIFE).